# Turn id back into a reference object in AppScript objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, sourceforge-appscript

I'm writing an app that talks to Mail using Objective-C-appscript (objc-appscript). I want to make a copy of the currently selected mail messages and perform some processing on it at a later -- at which time the current selection may have changed.

```
MLApplication *mail = [[MLApplication alloc] initWithBundleID: @"com.apple.mail"];
MLReference *ref = [mail selection];
id theSelection = [[ref getItem] copy];

// Do something here, which may change the contents of ref,  
// but that's okay since I made a copy in theSelection

MLMoveCommand *cmd = [[theSelection move] to: [[mail mailboxes] byName:@"test"]];

// This command should move the selected messages to the mailbox but fails  
// because theSelection

MLReference *ref2 = nil; // Need to turn theSelection into an MLReference *
MLMoveCommand *cmd = [[ref2 move] to: [[mail mailboxes] byName:@"test"]];
```

I need to turn theSelection back into an MLReference *. I'm sure this should be a simple operation, but I am new to appscript and require some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it needs to be an MLReference. Rather, I think it needs to be an AppScript list object. How do you turn an NSArray object into an AppScript list object?

Answer (score 0):

You can always cast theSelection to whatever type you want it to be.  You can also query it and find out what type it thinks it is using the `class` method.  You probably don't have to do this though.

For example,

`NSString *something = [(MLReference *)theSelection someFuncIMadeUp];`

You can read all about the runtime stuff (like the class method) in the apple doc:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I know that theSelection is a NSCFArray, but I want to turn it back into an MLReference. Looking at the MLReference headers, there's a class method called referenceWithAppData:id)appData aemReference:(id)aemReference but I'm unsure what parameters I need to place there.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming Apple event IPC uses proxy objects like Distributed Objects, but that's not the case: it's RPC + queries. (Think XPath over XML-RPC as a rough analogy.) It's a common misconception - Apple themselves totally fail at explaining it - but grasping Apple events' query-based nature is essential to controlling scriptable apps effectively.

Anyway, here's where you're going wrong:

```
id theSelection = [[ref getItem] copy];
```

This line copies an MLReference object identifying Mail's `selection` property, but as a reference is basically analogous to a URL that's effectively a no-op.

```
MLMoveCommand *cmd = [[theSelection move] to: [[mail mailboxes] byName:@"test"]];
```

This line tells Mail to move the object(s) it finds at the referenced location. That command may or may not work depending on how capable Mail's scripting support is (some apps may be capable of manipulating multiple objects with a single command; others are limited to a single object per command). But even if it does work, it will be operating on whatever's selected at the time the command is sent - which isn't what you're after.

The correct solution in this case is to use a `get` command to retrieve a list of references (in this case, an NSArray of MLReference instances), which you can later iterate over to move each of the referenced messages in turn. Fortunately, the references that Mail returns identify messages by id, which means that they should continue pointing to the original message objects even if they're moved in the meantime. (By-index and by-name references are much less stable, so you need to be a lot more careful working with apps that use those.)

For example (error checking omitted for clarity):

```
MLApplication *mail = [MLApplication applicationWithBundleID: @"com.apple.mail"];
NSArray *messageRefs = [[mail selection] getItem];
// do other stuff here
MLReference *message;
for (message in messageRefs) {
    MLMoveCommand *cmd = [[mail move: message] to: [[mail mailboxes] byName: @"test"]];
    id result = [cmd send];
}
```

See the appscript manual for more information. Also, ASTranslate is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used this method in pure AppleScript, but the speed of sending messages to each message versus sending it to an entire list of messages is much slower. In my other implementation, I'm using NSAppleScript to compile a script that does the "copy selection to theSelection" and move operation. I figured that was more hacky than using AppScript.

Comment: So, I figured I could do everything I wanted in AppleScript in AppScript or Scripting Bridge. Unfortunately, SB doesn't enable the move list to mailbox command, only the move message to mailbox command.

Comment: Is this AppleScript line possible from within AppScript? "copy selection to theSelection" How are instance variables handled in AppScript? All the examples I could find did not mention them.

Comment: When given an application reference as direct parameter, AppleScript's `copy` statement sends either a `get` or `duplicate` command to the app depending on what the `to` parameter is. So it's a red herring; ignore it and use `get` here. If Mail's `move` command accepts a list of references (which is pretty rare but not unknown; Finder allows this, for example), then to take advantage of this in appscript lose the `for` statement and change the `move` command to: `[[mail move: messageRefs] to: [[mail mailboxes] byName: @"test"]]`.

Comment: "I figured I could do everything I wanted in AppleScript in AppScript or Scripting Bridge." - SB, no; its attempt to dress up AE IPC as Cocoa/OO result in partly crippled functionality and a tendency for application incompatibilities. Appscript, yes, since it not only preserves AE semantics but also tries very hard to be quirk-for-quirk compatible with AS. Appscript is slightly more prescriptive than AS though, so sometimes AS will let you express an operation in several ways that can only be written one way in appscript - using `copy` as an alias for `duplicate`/`get` being one example.

Comment: Once again, ASTranslate is your friend. While it's only an Apple event sniffer, not a full code translation tool, if you know how to write commands in AS then it will give you lots of hints on how to write the equivalent code for appscript.